# keras : converting numpy ndarray of strings to numpy ndarray of floats :: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to run a neural network based model using keras for 
which numpy array can be used as input for training data and labels. 
The data is originally stored in a text file and the long 0/1 
sequences are not comma seperated which I have read 
in numpy array of 65 rows and 7116 columns.

```
print('X.shape ', X.shape)
X.shape  (65, 7116)

print('X \n ', X)
X 
 [['0' '1' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
 ['1' '0' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
 ['1' '0' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
 ...
 ['0' '0' '1' ... '0' '0' '0']
 ['1' '0' '0' ... '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '1' ... '0' '0' '0']]
```

X is my input data which is currently 
    print('type(X) ', type(X))
    type(X)

```
print('type(X[0]) ', type(X[0]))
type(X[0])  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print('type(X[0][0]) ', type(X[0][0]))
type(X[0][0])  <class 'numpy.str_'>
```

Now as `type(X[0][0])` is `<class 'numpy.str_'>` and not float, 
I can not use this as an input to NN.

I have used following methods but these are giving an error
    `X1 = X.astype(float) # ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'`

```
x1 = np.asarray(X, dtype=float) # ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'

X1 = np.array(X)
np.float_(X1) # ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'

print('X1 ', X1)
```

How can it be transformed so that it can be used as an input to NN.

The output Y is already reshpaed :

```
Y = Y.reshape((65,1))  # Y was in pandas data frame originally
print(type(Y)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(Y.shape) # (65, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4000, input_dim=7116, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X, Y, verbose=2) 

Currently the fit function says:
Epoch 1/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-344e05f836de> in <module>()
     10 model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
     11 
---> 12 model.fit(X, Y, verbose=2)

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
    861                               class_weight=class_weight,
    862                               sample_weight=sample_weight,
--> 863                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
    864 
    865     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1,

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, **kwargs)
   1428                               val_f=val_f, val_ins=val_ins, shuffle=shuffle,
   1429                               callback_metrics=callback_metrics,
-> 1430                               initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
   1431 
   1432     def evaluate(self, x, y, batch_size=32, verbose=1, sample_weight=None):

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _fit_loop(self, f, ins, out_labels, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_f, val_ins, shuffle, callback_metrics, initial_epoch)
   1077                 batch_logs['size'] = len(batch_ids)
   1078                 callbacks.on_batch_begin(batch_index, batch_logs)
-> 1079                 outs = f(ins_batch)
   1080                 if not isinstance(outs, list):
   1081                     outs = [outs]

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   2266         updated = session.run(self.outputs + [self.updates_op],
   2267                               feed_dict=feed_dict,
-> 2268                               **self.session_kwargs)
   2269         return updated[:len(self.outputs)]
   2270 

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    898     try:
    899       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 900                          run_metadata_ptr)
    901       if run_metadata:
    902         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1102             feed_handles[subfeed_t] = subfeed_val
   1103           else:
-> 1104             np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
   1105 
   1106           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and

D:\Installed_Programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    490 
    491     """
--> 492     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    493 
    494 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Y'
```

I have checked if there is any blank space / Nan / other characters between individual elements of numpy array. But there is no element of that type which could lead to this error. So I guess it is the string element of numpy array which is causing the trouble.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a value of `'Y'` in your array? That seems to be what the error is saying

Comment: @ALollz Hi Alollz, Y seems to be in good shape, please see ::    
                      print(type(Y))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
                      print(Y)   # [[0]                                          
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]
 [1]]

Comment: I don't care about the variable `Y`. The issue is that one of your string values within your variable `X` is the string `'Y'`, which cannot be converted to a float.

Comment: @user9905807 What do you get if you run `(X=='Y').sum()` ?

Comment: @ChrisA Thank you so much for helping me to figure this out... print((X=='Y').sum()) gives 3 which is where the problem lies

Comment: @user9905807 Ok, good start, you can fix those 3 by running `X = np.where(X=='Y', 1, X)`.  It's probably a good idea while you're at it to also check for the string' `'N'`

Comment: print((X=='Y').sum())  # 3
print((X=='N').sum())  # 0

Comment: @ChrisA I guess there an 'R' too was there:                                               
print('Y : ', (X=='Y').sum())
print('N : ', (X=='N').sum())
print('R : ', (X=='N').sum())

print('N : ', (Y=='N'))
print('Y : ', (Y=='Y'))
print('R : ', (Y=='R'))
                                                                                                                             X = np.where(X=='Y', 1, X)
X = np.where(X=='R', 1, X)                               after doing this it worked.... Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @user9905807 Happy to help!

Comment: @ALollz Thank you so much....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the `Y` values are intended to be 'yes'/1...

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to cast the `'Y'` values to `1`:

```
X = np.where(X=='Y', 1, X)
```